# How can I make nats stream replay messages

Tags: nats.io

I have a jetstream-enabled, limited-policy stream on nats. All messages stream fine for couple days. Now, I am wishing to replay the messages to the consumer/subscriber. How can I do it? Thank you.

I am expecting to replay the stream messages in last 24 hours with the same consumer/subscriber

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

How things work in NATS:

**Stream**: Is responsible for storing and replicating messages (if replication factor > 1 is used).

**Consumer**: Is a "view" into a `Stream`. It tracks acknowledgements, last sequence etc. Consumer is Server-side construct. Your app does not need to track sequences, even between app restarts.

If you want to replay messages from a `Stream`, the simplest answer is to create a new `Consumer` with properly defined starting point, called `Deliver Policy` which can be

- All - all messages from the Stream are delivered
- Last - only new messages will be delivered, starting from last current sequence when creating the consumer
- New - only new messages will be delivered
- Start Sequence - define from which Stream Sequence messages will be delivered
- **Start Time** - from what point in time in `Stream` messages will be delivered.

For your use case, it would be a new Consumer with `Deliver Policy` set to `Start Time` of `now() - 24h`.

You can consider using `OrderedConsumer` - a fast, lightweight, single replica ephemeral(meaning it will be cleaned up by the server after not being used for some time) consumer.

**Not sure what language you use, but here is an example in `Go`:**

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 60*time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    nc, err := nats.Connect("nats://127.0.0.1:4222")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    js, err := jetstream.New(nc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stream, err := js.Stream(ctx, "stream")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    restartFrom := time.Now().Add(-time.Hour * 24)
    cons, err := stream.OrderedConsumer(ctx, jetstream.OrderedConsumerConfig{
        DeliverPolicy: jetstream.DeliverByStartTimePolicy,
        OptStartTime:  &restartFrom,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = cons.Consume(func(msg jetstream.Msg) {
        fmt.Println(string(msg.Data()))
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What If I would recreate the consumer, technically, I could replay the messages from a stream, given that my Deliver policy: ALL. Am I have the right thoughts?

Comment: Yes, if you want to replay all messages from a Stream, a consumer with DeliveryPolicy = All will do exactly that.